# Will SC_THREAD in SystemC create a real thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, systemc

I debugged following code in Visual Studio 2008 (64 bit) by setting break point at the start of `do_test1` and `do_test2`, to my suprise, the code is running in the same thread of the `sc_main` function.

I didn't debug in Linux environment. However, by searching the source code, I found the `"pthread.h"` was included by some SystemC library source code.

Question 1: In Windows, will the `SC_THREAD` create a real thread? Or it is always in the same thread of `sc_main`? If this is the case, may I say `SC_THREAD` is creating a "fake" thread?

Question 2: In Linux, since `"pthread.h"` is included, will `SC_THREAD` create a new thread?

Question 3: In Windows and Linux, did I miss some settings to enable the real thread?

========================================

Following code is from this website:

http://www.asic-world.com/systemc/systemc_time4.html#Example_:_sc_event

```
    #include <systemc.h>

    SC_MODULE (events) {
      sc_in<bool> clock;

      sc_event  e1;
      sc_event  e2;

      void do_test1() {

        while (true) {
          // Wait for posedge of clock
          wait();
          cout << "@" << sc_time_stamp() <<" Starting test"<<endl;
          // Wait for posedge of clock
          wait();
          cout << "@" << sc_time_stamp() <<" Triggering e1"<<endl;
          // Trigger event e1
          e1.notify(5,SC_NS);
          // Wait for posedge of clock
          wait();
          // Wait for event e2
          wait(e2);
          cout << "@" << sc_time_stamp() <<" Got Trigger e2"<<endl;
          // Wait for posedge of clock
          wait();
          cout<<"Terminating Simulation"<<endl;
          sc_stop(); // sc_stop triggers end of simulation
        }
      }

      void do_test2() {
        while (true) {
          // Wait for event e2
          wait(e1);
          cout << "@" << sc_time_stamp() <<" Got Trigger e1"<<endl;
          // Wait for 3 posedge of clock
          wait(3);
          cout << "@" << sc_time_stamp() <<" Triggering e2"<<endl;
          // Trigger event e2
          e2.notify();
        }
      }

      SC_CTOR(events) {
        SC_CTHREAD(do_test1,clock.pos());
        SC_CTHREAD(do_test2,clock.pos());
      }
    }; 

    int sc_main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
      sc_clock clock ("my_clock",1,0.5);
      events  object("events");
        object.clock (clock); 
      sc_start();  // Run the simulation till sc_stop is encountered
      return 0;// Terminate simulation
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No & Yes. It depends on your SystemC library configuration.

You can configure SystemC to use pthread or Windows native thread. So when you compile and run your SystemC design, it creates REAL threads. However, by default, in UNIX environment, it won't use pthread by default because system calls are expensive. And SystemC only run threads one by one no matter how you configure your SystemC to use pthread or Window native thread. Because it only runs one thread at a time, using its user-level thread is faster than others because no system-calls are involved.

Why SystemC does not run all schedule threads at once? It's another question.

Comment: Thanks. Q1: How to configure SystemC to use pthread or Windows native thread?  Q2: You mentioned "And SystemC only run threads one by one no matter how you configure your SystemC to use pthread or Window native thread.", my question is: then what's the point of enable pthread or windows native thread? Q3. Why SystemC does not run all schedule threads at once? (I'm really interested in this question)

Comment: A1. configure --enable-pthreads
A2. It just uses pthread or Windows native thread to maintain the threads' data, suspension, and resume. SystemC uses its built-in QuickThreads by default.

Comment: A3. Threads can easily be modified to run in parallel mode if it uses pthread. But in those threads, when you needs to read/write ports/signals, or access kernel's resource, SystemC must be rewritten to lock and protect these data to avoid data race. And extra locks and waits could cause those threads become sequential run. And those lock/wait system-call could introduce extra overheads. Moreover, now SystemC signal and kernel or related data structure for the simulation, they do not have such mechanism to prevent data race if threads are running in parallel.

Answer (score 15):

**Short answer:**

Threading libraries, be they user-level threads (lighter and faster for context switching ) or kernel-level threads, are not used to provide real concurrency. Rather, they are used to implement coroutine semantics of `SC_THREAD` processes.

**Long answer:**

SystemC has 3 types of processes (i.e., units of concurrency), the most important of which are only two:

1. `SC_METHOD`s are methods (similar to `always` statements in Verilog) that
   execute in their entirety ***in zero time*** when triggered by an event. They cannot
   use `wait` to wait for a time interval or event occurrence.
2. `SC_THREAD`s are methods (like `initial` statements in Verilog) that
   execute only once, but they can use `wait` to wait for particular
   events or periods of time, and can use loops to emulate `always`
   statements (so an `SC_THREAD` can consume time).

For an implementation perspective, there is no problem with `SC_METHOD`s because they are just like methods registered with the SystemC kernel to be called when triggered. However, for `SC_THREAD`s, although they are defined as member functions, their behavior is not like ordinary routines. They are called [***coroutines***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine):

> Subroutines that allow multiple entry points for suspending and resuming execution at certain locations.

The SystemC kernel doesn't furnish *real* concurrency for system-level or RTL models. It only offers *simulated* concurrency through the process construct. Therefore, when writing high-level models, you don't have to use synchronization primitives (e.g., locks or semaphores) to protect data shared by different processes, since at any one time, only one process is executing and it cannot be aborted by the SystemC kernel (execution switches to the next process ready to execute only when the currently executing process relinquishes control. Still synchronization can be used, but SystemC promotes the use of ***message passing*** in ***channels*** for communication among processes. This is an advantage, since it reduces complexity. However, there are disadvantages too. SystemC models execute sequentially (not parallelized) so they don't utilize multicore architectures to speed up simulations. This is a hot research area where simulation performance is desired.

Anyway, the SystemC kernel thus implements ***cooperative scheduling***, where each `SC_THREAD` willingly relinquishes control (by using `wait`) to allow other `SC_THREAD` processes to execute. If you have an infinite loop inside an `SC_THREAD` process that never relinquishes control, the whole simulation will be stuck there and simulation time won't advance. The same is true about `SC_METHOD`s, which must return for the SystemC kernel to regain control.

In order to implement that cooperative scheduling strategy using coroutines, a threading library is used (e.g., pthreads, or QuickThread which is included in the SystemC source code) to enable `SC_THREAD`'s (launched as threads) to suspend themselves and enable the kernel to resume them later. Read [this article](http://www.design-reuse.com/articles/9402/understanding-and-extending-systemc-userthread-package-to-ia64-platform.html) to know more about this.